# asterisk agi dial with DTMF also LIMIT

Tags: asterisk, dtmf, agi

am trying to do DTMF also limiting the call duration, however, I can't get both to work, it's either one or the other in the dial command. Please help me.

```
$agi->exec("DIAL","SIP/gateway/18009993355,30,D(1234),L(100000)")
```

Comment: Please read carefully documentation for dial command. You L() will be 4-d ardgument of dial, there are only 3 in doc.

Comment: Really ok I didn't know that even though I have tried reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the , between the )and L should work:

```
$agi->exec("DIAL","SIP/gateway/18009993355,30,D(1234)L(100000)")
```